# Coordinates of a pt., inside a curve

Tags: circles

$Q.(\lambda,\lambda + 1) \text {lies inside the curve } x= \sqrt{25-y^{2}} \space and \ y-axis, \ find \ \lambda$

Attempt-
From the given equation, we deduce that the shape is circle.

For a point inside the circle, the equation of circle is- $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c<0$

Plugging in the coordinates of the point, we get- $\lambda^{2}+(\lambda+1)^2+2 \lambda g+ 2( \lambda + 1) f+c<0$

Now, this is where I run into trouble, how do I find the values of g, f, and c.

I tried equating the value of x, with the radius formula to get their value but no luck.

$\sqrt {g^2+f^2-c} = \sqrt {25-y^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The equation $x=\sqrt{5-y^2}$ represents the semicircle with positive $x$  and with center $(0,0)$ and radius $r=5$ .

The point $Q=(x,y)=(\lambda, 1+\lambda)$ is in this semicircle if:
$$
\begin{cases}
-5\le y\le 5\\
 0\le x \le \sqrt{5-y^2}\\
\end{cases}
$$
that, for $x=\lambda$ and $y=1+\lambda$ becomes:
$$
\begin{cases}
-5\le (1+\lambda)\le 5\\
 0\le \lambda \le \sqrt{5-(1+\lambda)^2}\\
\end{cases}
$$

can you solve this?

---

From:
$$
\begin{cases}
-5\le (1+\lambda)\\
(1+\lambda)\le 5\\
 0\le \lambda \\
\end{cases}
$$
we have $0\le \lambda\le 3$
and, for $\lambda$in this interval, the other inequality becomes:
$$
\lambda^2\le 25-(1+\lambda)^2
$$
with solution $-4\le \lambda \le 3$. So the solution of the starting system is $0\le \lambda \le 3$.

Comment: Is there a way without using inequalities?

Comment: I don't see other ways, But the solution of the inequalities is really simple. I add to my answer.